# ElasticSearch - I need to import indexes from an old server that is no longer onilne to the new Server

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, graylog

So I first attempted to shutdown elasticsearch on the original server, bring up the replacement, copy everything to the same location but that didnt work so I just started fresh.  I now need to be able to search those old indexes to show that we have a years worth of log retention.  I dont think snapshot or reindex will work because the old indexes are not currently attached to a live server.... But I may be wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Old servers indexes begin with graylog2_2xx and graylog2_1xx
New Server graylog_1x

Comment: Is there any chance to bring up the old Elasticsearch cluster again?

Comment: Are the source and target Elasticsearch versions different? Are you sure there is no corruption during copy? Ideally, If you move the data folder to a new location,the shard should go online.

Comment: "The old indices are not currently attached to a live server", then how do you intend to retrieve anything if they are not accessible? Depending on the version you have migrated from and to, there is a standard procedure to migrate the indices, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/reindex-upgrade.html